# More compact relative dates in log?

Tags: git

Consider this custom git log output which uses `--date=relative` and the format string `%ar` for author date, relative[1]:

```
* c44addf - (21 minutes ago) adding e on dev - Jonah (dev)
* 2506d90 - (22 minutes ago) adding d - Jonah
| * 310855e - (22 minutes ago) adding e - Jonah (HEAD, master)
|/  
* 7b47b37 - (31 minutes ago) 2nd commit on dev - Jonah
* db00522 - (30 minutes ago) master 2nd commit - Jonah
* c58c898 - (32 minutes ago) initial - Jonah
```

The relative date display is more verbose than needed.  Instead of:

```
(31 minutes ago)
```

I would prefer:

```
(31 m)
```

Is this possible?

[1] Full command is `log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --date=relative --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h    %C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)%C(bold     yellow)%d%C(reset)' --all`

Comment: What to show if it will be `a month ago`?

Comment: How about "1 mon", "2 mon", etc.  This details isn't important -- the question is about customizing the display in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in way to output custom date formats in the manner that you are looking for.

I checked the git log documentation and the only relative date pretty format configuration available is `%cr` for committer date and `%ar` for author date and you're already using the the latter format so that won't work.

But you can use a bit of command line magic and a simple python script to get the job done. Here's how I did it:

python script called prettyDate.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import fileinput
import datetime
import sys

def prettydate(d):
    diff = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - d
    s = diff.seconds
    if diff.days > 7 or diff.days < 0:
        return d.strftime('%d %b %y')
    elif diff.days == 1:
        return '1 d'
    elif diff.days > 1:
        return '{} ds'.format(diff.days)
    elif s <= 1:
        return 'just now'
    elif s < 60:
        return '{} s'.format(s)
    elif s < 120:
        return '1 m'
    elif s < 3600:
        return '{} ms'.format(s/60)
    elif s < 7200:
        return '1 h'
    else:
        return '{} hs'.format(s/3600)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    for line in fileinput.input():
        lineSplit = line.split(' ')
        commit = lineSplit[0]
        timestamp = lineSplit[1]

        gitDt = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(timestamp))

        print commit + ' - (' + prettydate(gitDt) + ')'
```

Command to output the date:

```
git log --format="%h %at" | python prettyDate.py
```

The above `git log` statement will return the commit id and a Unix timestamp, which is piped to the python script for formatting. The script can be adjusted to whatever format you prefer and you can create an alias if you don't want to type out the entire command each time.

Example output:

```
b82462e - (2 ms)
i81362f - (8 hs)
j85462g - (1 d)
```